# AFNetworking - queue request

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have question Is it correct solution to invoke request inside success block of other? Should not prepare any complication? Because sometimes I receive fail action and I wonder could be due that fact?

```
[[httpClient instance] getPath:@""
     parameters:@""
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //Success code


            [[httpClient instance] getPath:@""
     parameters:@""}
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //Success code
     } 
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             //Error code
     }];

     } 
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             //Error code
     }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesting requests in completion blocks is not only fine, it's common if the second request relies on data from the first request.

Error -999 (NSURLErrorCancelled) is called when an asynchronous URL request is cancelled.  Look in your code for calls to `[AFHTTPClient -cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:path:]` or `[AFURLConnectionOperation -cancel]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that calling getPath:... again in the first success block is not the cause of the error you are getting. Anyway, could you edit your question and add more information about that error?

Also you should consider to creating two `AFHTTPRequestOperation` with the `AFHTTPClient` method `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` and set the second dependent on the first one with the `NSOperation` method `addDependency:`, and then add those operations to the HTTP client `operationQueue`.

Comment: I receive error -999, which means current active request has been closed and  am m wonder it could be that reason